# How to programmatically return to previous view controller without navigation controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I want to return to the previous/root view controller after a certain method finish running. I have found code that could work but I'm not using a navigation controller. I have tried [Programmatically changing View Controllers without Navigation Controller Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132511/programmatically-changing-view-controllers-without-navigation-controller-swift) but I am not sure how to code it in obj-c. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you went to your current VC from root VC ?

Comment: I have a button that when clicked goes to the second VC

Answer (score 1):

If you have presented your view controller (not embeded in a container) than you can simply call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES/NO completion:nil];
```

at the end of your certain method.

This turns out from the View Controller Programming Guide for iOS

> To dismiss a presented view controller, call the
>   dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: method of the presenting
>   view controller. **You can also call this method on the presented view
>   controller itself.** When you call the method on the presented view
>   controller, UIKit automatically forwards the request to the presenting
>   view controller.